# Method invocation conversions

Tags: java, autoboxing

I was trying to understand how the overloaded methods are called with conversions.Let me explain my question with a example I am trying

```
public class Autoboxing {

    public void meth(Integer i){
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }
    public void meth(long i){
        System.out.println("Long");
    }
    public void meth(int... i){
        System.out.println("int");
    }

    public void meth(Object i){
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Autoboxing box= new Autoboxing();
        box.meth(5);
    }
}
```

here output is : Long

Why method with argument long is called instead in Wrapper Integer.Please explain.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27940321/1878022 if this help to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Method Overloaded form comes and user try to invoke among of then compiler chosen in this manner,

1. Exact match with data-type if find then invoke immediatly.
   1.1 if exact match not match then compiler try to match with broader type-data type.
2. if above case fail then it start to match with Auto-Boxing manner.
3. all above 2-case fail then start to match with vararg case.
4. all above case failure while gives error like cann't resolve method-name.

so in your case 5 is `integer(primitive)` so it start to match with `int`' (1-case), but fail so try to match with broader data-type.
here, in your case it match with `long`(primitive) which is broader then '`int`'

So, that you get "`Long`" output.

So, likewise compiler behaviors while overloading scenario came.

Answer (score 5):

Overloading resolution has three stages. The first stage tries to find a matching method without using auto-boxing and varargs (which is why `meth(long i)` is chosen and not `meth(Integer i)`). Only if the first stage doesn't find any match, the second stage tries to find a matching method with auto-boxing.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that
here precedence is 1st is widening then autoboxing an then varargs.
As widening a primitive parameter is much better than auto-boxing.